# Storing list of position in sharedPreferences, and retrieve in another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-sharedpreferences

I want to do similar like [this](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/), I have used cardview with recyclerview. I added favourite button cardview below you can see the full code. In recyclerview adapter I print the Toast as per position and its working fine, now I need to save the int value of position in shared Preferences in arraylist and display those arraylist in next intent.

This is my recyclerview adapter

```
public void onBindViewHolder(NameViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(names.get(position).textView);
    holder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putInt("key", position);  //may be or may not be.
            //add code here to save position in array
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Fav "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

cardview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="3dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:cardElevation="3dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ff9901"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/favourite"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Provide me getting arraylist from prefrences and how to use in ListView too.

Comment: can you please add your activity java code ?

Comment: Which part of code do i need to post? I have already posted how i called the favourite button. If the favourite button is pressed in the list then the items should be added into sharedprefrences.

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
editor.putInt("key", position);
```

put this:

```
editor.apply();
```

I think you should add these value to a list instead, then pass the list to another activity, as a param,  that will be a better approach.

**Edit 2**

```
// take a global string 
String positions = "";

 public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            /*   here first concat the current item position with the string, then put that in the pref  */
            positions = positions + position + " ";
            editor.putString("key", positions); 

        }



//in the next activity, 
String key = sp.getString("key");
String[] positions = key.split(" ");
// Now you have all the positions in the next activity and its in the String datatype
// if you wanna int datatype there, parse it through Integer.parseInt(string).
```

Comment: ya, If i did add editor.putInt("key',position); only one value will be added isn't it? in the list, users may click multiple list items, therefore I need to send multiple position. How can i do that?

Comment: I think list will be a better  aproach, just initialize an ArrayList<Integer> list in the constuctor, and when the user clicks on the item, list.add(position); , whenever you wanna redirect the user to the next activity, put the list in the constructor assign that to the new list in next activity... need more help?

Comment: Will you please Answer in a code? I am newbie. And I need to save in sharedPrefrences so that when user can see their favourite items later when they want.

Comment: I need to save in the sharedPrefrences any how.

Comment: May be this may work, I will try this and inform you back @zee433

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider to pass data in bundle through the intent. If you don't need to store this information after app closing, then use that way.

If you want to also save your data, through re-running the app, then SharedPreferences is fine, here is code, how you can implement this functionality. First let's write snippet that helps you to restore items and update adapter with them:

```
private static final String CHECKED_ITEMS_REF = "checked_items";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

private void restoreAdapterState(RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
    Set<String> savedCheckedItems = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(CHECKED_ITEMS_REF, new HashSet<>());
    List<Integer> checkedPositions = convertToCheckedItems(savedCheckedItems);
    for (Integer position : checkedPositions) {
        //update somehow info about checked items, for example in 
        //adapter you can store set of checked positions and in
        //onBindViewHolder function check is ViewHolder position
        //contained in you set
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}

private List<Integer> convertToCheckedItems(Set<String> checkedItems) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String itemPositionStr : checkedItems) {
        int position = Integer.parseInt(itemPositionStr);
        result.add(position);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that you can follow my advise in comment and then `restoreAdapterState` will be modified:

```
private void restoreAdapterState(MultiCheckedAdapter adapter) {
    Set<String> savedCheckedItems = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(CHECKED_ITEMS_REF, new HashSet<>());
    List<Integer> checkedPositions = convertToCheckedItems(savedCheckedItems);
        adapter.setCheckedPositions(new HashSet<Integer>(checkedPositions));
}
```

And in `MultyCheckedAdapter` you will have something like:

```
private Set<Integer> checkedPositions = new HashSet<>();

public setCheckedPositions(Set<Integer> checkedPositions) {
    this.checkedPositions = checkedPositions;
    for (Integer position : checkedPositions) {
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}

...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (checkedPositions.contains(position)) {
        //use one binding
    } else {
        //use another binding
    }
}

...
```

Then you need to change your snippet:

```
private Set<Integer> checkedPositions = new HashSet<>();

public void onBindViewHolder(NameViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(names.get(position).textView);
    holder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //check somehow is current item checked or not.
            //for example store set of checked items in adapter
            //let's say it declaration is Set<Integer> checkedItems;
            if (checkedPositions.contains(position)) {
                checkedPositions.remove(position);
                removeCheckedItem(position);
            } else {
                checkedPositions.add(position);
                saveCheckedItem(position);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void saveCheckedItem(int position) {
    Set<String> savedCheckedItems = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(CHECKED_ITEMS_REF, new HashSet<>());
    String positionStr = String.valueOf(position);
    if (!savedCheckedItems.contains(positionStr)) {
        savedCheckedItems.add(positionStr);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet(CHECKED_ITEMS_REF, savedCheckedItems).apply();
    }
}

private void removeCheckedItem(int position) {
    Set<String> savedCheckedItems = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(CHECKED_ITEMS_REF, new HashSet<>());
    String positionStr = String.valueOf(position);
    if (savedCheckedItems.contains(positionStr)) {
        savedCheckedItems.remove(positionStr);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet(CHECKED_ITEMS_REF, savedCheckedItems).apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it's too complex for me.. As  I am a new to android.  Anyway thank you Micheal

Comment: What exactly is hard for you? If you code your first app with lists and shared states, then you must understand how are list, adapters, shared preferences work. Also you must know, how write programms in java. If we assume that, then what exactly is hard for you? I can edit my answer and explain these misunderstandings

Comment: You have four parts of code. I am really confused where to place them all? and what is that  what does HashSet<> do? what are set<> doing? All these stuff are  complex and heard for first time  thank you?? Can you tell me, In sharedPrefrences Context.Mode_APPEND is for appending the value instead of replacing  one? Then why we won't use here ? I think using Mode_APPEND  will be  the clean code?

Comment: I use mode private, to not allow another applications to get access to your shared prefs. Then as for <>, sorry but it was introduced by Java 7 long time ago, in Java 6 you had to write `Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();`, in Java 7 you can write `Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();`. As for parts last part you need to place in your snippet. 3rd part in your custom adapter (I just used my name for it), 2nd part is a enhanced part of first part. First part you need to place in second Activity or whatever, where you construct new list view, or what you have there.

Comment: @Queendevelopers Sorry, but I can not write whole programm for you, I just explained, how you can solve your issue. Your questions seems for me to point that you need to see whole programm, but it now working like that, it's stackoverflow. So, sorry, for my rudeness, but I would suggest to you to read more tutorials about java and android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StringBuilder for this purpose. Append/Replace based on the item click and then save it to shared preference as a string.

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(NameViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sp.getStringPreference("key", ""))
    holder.textView.setText(names.get(position).textView);
    holder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            sb.append(position);
            editor.putString("key", sb.toString()); 
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Fav "+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Integer items can be retrieved from String using Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(index));
But if you need to just pass the values to next activity and don't need in future then you can use an ArrayList and pass it via Intent.

Comment: sp  not  found you defind at StringBuilder in secondLine?

Comment: sp is your shared preference, you can make it global.

Comment: Okay, great I will  give this a try when I return home and I will comment you back! ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this to store

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("key", position);  //may be or may not be.
editor.commit;
```

and in your other activity use this to retrieve

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            int position=sp.getInt("key");
```

you may also try this 
Like in your Activity A
Create a Intent of Activity B

```
Intent intent =new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("key",position);
startActivity(intent);
```

in your activity B

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
int position Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("key"));
```

**EDIT**

use the arraylist and transfer it from one activity to another

```
 ArrayList<Integer> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
    mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_0);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_1);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_2);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_3);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_4);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_5);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_6);
            mThumbIds.add(R.drawable.sample_7);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                ArrayList list=mThumbIds;
                Intent intent= new Intent(A.this,B.class);
                       intent.putExtra("list",mThumbIds);
                intent.putExtra("position",position);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
               //   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold,R.anim.slide_in_left);
                    startActivity(intent);




            }
        });
```

now use this in your ativity B

```
    Intent intent =getIntent();


        int position=Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("position").toString());
        ArrayList<Integer> list= (ArrayList<Integer>) intent.getExtras().get("list");

int current_position=list.get(position)
```

Comment: This will replace value in sharedPrefrences if i click another, I need all the clicked value, For this it may need Context.MODE_APPED? or what? please re-edit your answer

Comment: for what purpose you want position of all

Comment: I have uploaded tutorial link above in my question. I want to make same like  that but that tutorial is so hard for me as i am newbie so i asked for a simple so that i can understand well