# Highlighted item on listview gone when new message arrived Android Studio

Tags: android

I have a listview and it automatically filter all sim messages from mobile then I highlighted the items on the listview through clicking and it works, but the problem is when there's new message all of the highlighted item gone.Is theres any solution to remain the highlighted item when new message arrived? I use the following code. Thanks I appreciate your response.

> [image: before] [image]
>
> layout : activitymain.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/textlistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/default_color"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> Broadcast Receiver : SMSReceiver.java

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static  final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) bundle.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMsg = "";
            SmsMessage smsMessage;
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    String format = bundle.getString("format");

                    smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);
                }
                else {
                    smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                }

                String msgBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                smsMsg +=msgBody;
            }
                text_message inst = text_message.Instance();
                inst.receive_data(smsMsg);
        }
    }
}}
```

> MainActivity : text_message.java

```
public void receive_data (final String smsMsg) {
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, list_items);
        text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.add(smsMsg);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> Filter messages : text_message.java

```
 public  void refreshInbox(){
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items);
    ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = cResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;

    do{
        str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) ;
        arrayAdapter.add(str);
    }while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
      }
```

Comment: Create another array of booleans and set value of selected items to true and based on boolean value change bg of item

Comment: @PraveenSP Thanks for your response but can you provide example? please

Comment: Ok how you are selecting views on clicking of the list view items can you post that adapter code ?

Comment: @PraveenSP  Declaring array list  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojFDI.png and this is the arrayadapter https://i.stack.imgur.com/upMxp.png and I use android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" to highlight the item on listview. thank you very much

Comment: I have written an answer go through it and let me know if works...

Comment: @PraveenSP whenever I receive message the result is always the same :( , note  I use android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" to highlight item before not setonitemclicklistener    but I try to run your code but the result is the same highlighted item was vanished, need help

Comment: @PraveenSP It goes like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD7P2.png , my activity layout http://i.stack.imgur.com/lwYIJ.png ,                                                      
  declaring selected http://i.stack.imgur.com/FO8oC.png and lastly receive data http://i.stack.imgur.com/hfhNa.png, but whenever message arrived it update all items in listview the highlighted color gone :(

Comment: I have updated my answer put the loop inside runnable ...let me know if it works

Comment: @PraveenSP whenever I clicked the receive message item on listview I get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/B08tH.png  the error comes from onItemClick, thanks for your response

Comment: Whenever you recieve messge you need to increment array size and copy old array content to new array

Comment: @PraveenSP  I get the idea thanks  but I always getting this error, dont know what to do

Comment: Which error ? actually ?

Comment: OnItemClickListener  this line  isSelected[position]=true; @PraveenSP

Comment: Yeah it is expected error .. we created array based on old sms list  so it size should be changed ... when new sms arrives...

Comment: I appreciate your response, it always crashes my app whenever I click the new item  how to prevent it? @PraveenSP still the highlighted color gone. :(

Comment: so when new message comes up the color is still not being highlighted ?

Comment: @PraveenSP Yes your right, the color is still not highlighted

Comment: the error you are getting is because of my code i.e isSelected thing so don't worry about it ... I will fix it and update you ..

Comment: @PraveenSP Thank you you're the best, it almost a week and I can't solve this problem Im stuck with this module :(

Comment: Don't worry It will be ressolved by morning ...

Comment: Reymark I have updated my answer check it ... I hope there will be no errors let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global array called isSelected like this

```
private boolean[] isSelected;
```

Then assign your array with the size like this

```
 isSelected=new boolean[arrayAdapter.getCount()]; // Do this after setting adapter
```

and .setOnItemClickListener on listview and when the click happens to make sure selected of that index is set to true like this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               isSelected[position]=!isSelected[position];
           }
       });
```

And in receive_data() select those selected positions again

```
public void receive_data (final String smsMsg) {
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, list_items);
        text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.add(smsMsg);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        boolean[] tempSelected=new boolean[arrayAdapter.getCount()];

        for(int i=0;i<isSelected.length;i++)
        {
             tempSelected[i]=isSelected[i];
             if(tempSelected[i])
             {
               text_listview.setItemChecked(i,true);
             }
        }

        isSelected=tempSelected;

}
```

Comment: Hi sensei sorry I know its a bit late , do you have any idea or solution to remain the highlighted item even you close the app? :/

Comment: You need to come up with some caching mechanism. If the list is less you can store in the sharedprefs if large you go for room or sqlite. Then from the stored data of that you need to highlight the item

Comment: I been shy asking again some help with you, but I coudn't find any source with this and I've tried shareprefs but I don't have idea how to apply this in color, can you help me if it is ok ? this the hardest module for me and I've give up searching

Comment: Don't be shy ... you can ask any doubts you have. I recommend you check this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/39115900 If you get any trouble ask a new question mentioning the error/problem you get, the community will try to help you. And don't give up on searching I know it's kind overwhelming but keep looking don't settle

Comment: it is necessary to convert the data to Gson array in order to save the list in sharedpref?

Comment: Yes it's a necessary