# Listview highlighted before clicking dialog box - Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

> I want to highlight a clicked `ListView` item after clicking the alert dialog box Read button; the code below works perfect, but the only issue is whenever I click the item, it's highlighted with the color before the dialog shows.

I had doubt there is missing on my code, please check this out. Thank you

[image]

> MainActivity.java

```
    private boolean[] isSelected; //global variable
    text_listview = findViewById(R.id.textlistview);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, list_items);
    text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    isSelected=new boolean[arrayAdapter.getCount()];

    text_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            alert_dialog(position);

        }
    });
}


public void alert_dialog(final int position){
    final SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(
            text_message.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
    pDialog.setTitleText("Highlight data?");
    pDialog.setContentText("Please choose the corresponding details");
    pDialog.setCancelText("Unread!");
    pDialog.setConfirmText("Read!");
    pDialog.showCancelButton(true);
    pDialog.show();
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                    sDialog.setTitleText("Successfully save!")
                            .setContentText("Item mark as Unread")
                            .setConfirmText("OK")
                            .showCancelButton(false)
                            .setCancelClickListener(null)
                            .setConfirmClickListener(null)
                            .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                            sDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    isSelected[position]=false;
                    text_listview.setItemChecked(position,false);
                }
            })
            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                    sDialog.setTitleText("Successfully save!")
                            .setContentText("Item mark as Read")
                            .setConfirmText("OK")
                            .showCancelButton(false)
                            .setCancelClickListener(null)
                            .setConfirmClickListener(null)
                            .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                            sDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    isSelected[position]=true;
                    text_listview.setItemChecked(position,true);
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

> layout activitymain.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/textlistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> drawable myselecter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@color/lightOrange" android:state_activated="true"
    /></selector>
```

Comment: use a custom adapter and keep the reference of selected items in list and use it in getview to set it

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kqjV0.png This is my custom adapter but it seems the output is always the same , please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `selector` You can solve this by setting the color programmatically.

So, first of all remove the selector xml file, and remove its relevant layout attribute.

Add the unread color to the dialog `setCancelClickListener1()` and the read color to the `setConfirmClickListener` using: 
    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_orange));

The `view` is the root of the clicked ListView row; and you can get it from the arguments of the `onItemClick`callback.

So, change the signature of the `alert_dialog()` method to accept a View:

```
text_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        alert_dialog(position, view); // <<<<<<<<<< here is the change

    }
});
```

And add adjusting the color in dialog clicks

```
public void alert_dialog(final int position, final View view){
    final SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(
            text_message.this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
    pDialog.setTitleText("Highlight data?");
    pDialog.setContentText("Please choose the corresponding details");
    pDialog.setCancelText("Unread!");
    pDialog.setConfirmText("Read!");
    pDialog.showCancelButton(true);
    pDialog.show();
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                    sDialog.setTitleText("Successfully save!")
                            .setContentText("Item mark as Unread")
                            .setConfirmText("OK")
                            .showCancelButton(false)
                            .setCancelClickListener(null)
                            .setConfirmClickListener(null)
                            .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                            sDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    isSelected[position]=false;
                    // text_listview.setItemChecked(position,false); // No need to this line

                    view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)); // Setting a transparent color for the unread item
                }
            })
            .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                    sDialog.setTitleText("Successfully save!")
                            .setContentText("Item mark as Read")
                            .setConfirmText("OK")
                            .showCancelButton(false)
                            .setCancelClickListener(null)
                            .setConfirmClickListener(null)
                            .changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
                            sDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    isSelected[position]=true;
                    // text_listview.setItemChecked(position,true); // No need to this
                   view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_orange)); // create  light_orange color resource in colors.xml
                }
            })
            .show();
            updateBooleanArray();
}
```

```
public void updateBooleanArray() {
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, list_items);
        text_listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        boolean[] tempSelected=new boolean[arrayAdapter.getCount()];

        for(int i=0;i<isSelected.length;i++)
        {
             tempSelected[i]=isSelected[i];
             if(tempSelected[i])
             {
               text_listview.setItemChecked(i,true);
             }
        }

        isSelected = tempSelected;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea, your code works well and I already tried this but it conflicts related to my post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107231/highlighted-item-on-listview-gone-when-new-message-arrived-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment109868075_62107231  Whenever new message arrived the highlighted item gone I use Broadcast Receiver @Zain

Comment: Hello MackyRV.. Can you tell.. Only the new highlighted item loses the color or all the items?

Comment: When I use your code above when I get  new message all of the highlighted item gone but my code above works all of the item remain when I receive messages but the only conflicts is it highlighed when I click item before the dialog box show, I dunno what's going on please help

Comment: So the problem appears when you receive a new message, even after you call `receive_data()` which provided in the referred question?

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm stuck with this module until now :( @Zain

Comment: The problem is when I use your code above the problem appears when I receive new message , my existing code above already solved the problem in receiving new message using selecter but the thing is it highlighted the item when clicking before alert show that shows image above, please @Zain

Comment: Hi @MackyRV .. yes I see, I examined the other questions' code, but can't see something conflicts with here, especially still here you're setting the value `isSelected[position]` which controls the color .. but I do believe that you can't achieve what you want using `selector` because selectors works on finger gestures (so there is no time to take the dialog action before coloring items) Please check updated answer maybe it does some refresh to solve it

Comment: @MackyRV If you'll be happy for some advice.. It would be better to change the architecture of the `ListView`, as the items colors are highly coupled with the ListView items; so they should be consolidated with the ListView adapter instead of creating a separate boolean array in the activity.. upon updating your adapter, no need to call call `receive_data()` each time you receive a message.. you'll just need to add the new message and `notifyDatasetChanged()` .. The other thing I want to tell ... if you used RecyclerView instead of ListView that will be much more easier. hope you solve it